# Change the target/action of the "like" button in a stream/wall post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is it possible to change the action of the "like" button on a stream/wall post so that, rather than "liking" the wall post itself, the user "likes" the subject/link in that wall post?

For instance, say we have a page (`example.com/foo`) that has a "like" button on it. We also then post a link to this page on the user's wall. We want to ensure that number of users who click "like" on the user's wall are reflected in the number shown in the "like" box shown on the `example.com/foo` page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't appear to be possible. Pages and posts are different types of objects, with different Like behaviors. Liking a wall post creates a [like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/), while Liking a page creates a [page fan](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/). (I'm no expert; I'm assuming this based on the documentation.)

You might remember that the action on a page used to be ["Become a fan"](http://www.google.com/search?q=become+a+fan+of+this+page+facebook&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wi&biw=1050&bih=1608). The distinction was more clear then.

If you're the one creating the post, your best option seems to be to add a note reminding everyone to visit and Like the actual page.